# Is it a bad practice to create multiple instance of Kernel in Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a ASP.Net Web Application with many Custom Server Controls.

Unfortunately, [Ninject could not inject dependency into CompositeControls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736271/how-inject-depedency-to-compositecontrol-using-ninject).

I'm new to Ninject; the following is my simple approach to solve the problem.

Since I have many Custom Server Controls, I'll end up creating a multiple of instance of StandardKernel.

Is it a bad design? **Please correct me if I'm wrong.** Thanks!

```
public interface ICalculate
{
    int Add(int x, int y);
}

public class Calculate : ICalculate
{
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public class DemoModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ICalculate>().To<Calculate>();
    }
}

public class MyServerControl : CompositeControl
{
    private TextBox TextBox1;
    private TextBox TextBox2;
    private Label Label1;

    public ICalculate Calculate { get; set; }

    public MyServerControl()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new DemoModule());
        Calculate = kernel.Get<ICalculate>();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        TextBox1 = new TextBox{ID = "TextBox1", Text = "1"};
        Controls.Add(TextBox1);

        TextBox2 = new TextBox {ID = "TextBox2", Text = "2"};
        Controls.Add(TextBox2);

        var button1 = new Button {ID = "Button1", Text = "Calculate"};
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        Controls.Add(button1);

        Label1 = new Label {ID = "Label1"};
        Controls.Add(Label1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value1 = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        int value2 = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);

        Label1.Text = "Result:" + Calculate.Add(value1,value2);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at my answer at your other question.

Comment: Creating multiple instances isn't bad per see, but creating an infinite amount of instances (such as one per web request, or even multiple per request) is a very bad idea, because of the performance implementations. The general rule of thumb however is to create just one instance for your entire application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, creating a multiple of instance of Ninject's kernel is bad practicle, because creating and configuration Ninject's kernel its a very expensive operation. In your case this will happen every time, when new control will created.

I think, be better make `IKernel` as static field, and use him as `Service Locator` pattern in `CompositeControl`

**UPD:** It's not so bad, but it works.

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static IKernel Kernel;

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new DemoModule());
        return kernel;
    }
}

public class MyServerControl : CompositeControl
{
    public ICalculate Calculate { get; set; }

    public MyServerControl()
    {
        Calculate = Global.Kernel.Get<ICalculate>(); // like service locator
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried look for ServiceLocator of Ninject; I couldn't find any documentation. Could you point me to a correct direction?

Comment: I did not know that I can create static Kernel. Thanks!